# Unable to load DLL 'ogr_wrap' or one of its dependencies

Tags: gdal

In my C# project, I have added GDAL and GDAL.Native nuget packages. When attempting

```
Geometry h = Ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(geometry);
```

I get

```
The type initializer for 'OSGeo.OGR.OgrPINVOKE' threw an exception
Unable to load DLL 'ogr_wrap' or one of its dependencies
```

ogr_wrap is there, not with all other dlls like ogr_csharp.dll, but in gdal/x64 subdir

Some other GDAL methods like GetGeoTransform, GetRasterBand etc work correctly.

Am I missing something?

GDAL is 3.7.2, VS is 17.8.2, .NET 8.0 (same behaviour in 7.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included the following in your code before using Ogr:

```cs
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
```